# Gregorian Calander in Medium Date Format

Tags: java, calendar, date-formatting, gregorian-calendar

I was just wondering if anyone can help me with my issue of trying to do a Gregorian Calender in medium date format. I am not sure if this is the best way to do it, however I cannot get a output in my println statement.

```
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1999);
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 12);  
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 25)
```

and another attempt was

```
SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy");
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
```

I basically want the printout to look like Dec 25 1999.

Answer (score 0):

Months are zero-index based so if you want to set December you have to use

```
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 11);
```

instead of

```
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 12);
```

Here is my code example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1999);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 11);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 25);
    Date date = calendar.getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy");
    String formattedDate = sdf.format(date);
    System.out.println(formattedDate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This ought to help:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1999);
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.DECEMBER);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 12);

    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy");
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
}
```

Comment: I can see that helps solves my problem. Thank you so much.

But for the sake of learning if a Gregorian Calender was already defined with that date and I had to output it in the same format how would that be done instead of me using cal.set to set the year and month and day?

Comment: You can skip the Calendar init part. The SimpleDateFormatter requires a Date object, so the Calendar is completely optional. Since GregorianCalendar is-a Calendar, you will have the .getTime() method which returns a Date.

Comment: That's Day of Month, and not month! For Month I have used Calendar.DECEMBER to avoid this kind of confusion. Please read carefully, or better still, try out the solution before commenting or down-voting.

Comment: Yup, you're right. Unfortunatelly I can't undo my downvote.

Comment: So again for the sake of learning if I wanted to put this into a toString I would simply.


DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy");
return ("Christmas Date:" + DateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));

Comment: public String toString(){ DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy");
 return dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()); }